# Solr: how to custom score

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, scoring

I'm using solr 4.5.

I would like to customize solr score using in my "formula" the termFreq and PhraseFreq (it depend if in the query i have an term or a phrase).

Now I'm using in a url request the param:

```
sort=myFormula desc
```

it works but my problem is that in output i want also the output of my formula, now the solution is or to put the formula also into `fl` param or to customize the score :) and i'm looking for the last one solution.

Please, do you have any suggest or link/guide to give me to learn how is it possible customize the solr score? I'm searching on google but no results relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing your own CustomScoreQuery? The second example [here](http://spykem.blogspot.com/2013/06/plug-in-external-score-to-solr.html) as well as this [blog post](http://dev.fernandobrito.com/2012/10/building-your-own-lucene-scorer/) talk about how to do it.